# Synchronized Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, data

I want to use Synchronized Data Extensions as a standard data extension but i am not able to copy data extension .

I Created the same fields into the standard data extension now how can we get the record from sync DE?

What query we need to write and where ?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following SQL query to copy data from a Salesforce Synchronised Data Extension to a regular Data Extension.

Following example is based on the Account object.

```
SELECT *
FROM Account_Salesforce
```

However if you are doing this from a child business unit, you'll need to add `.ent` prefix.

```
SELECT *
FROM ent.[Account_Salesforce]
```

You can follow these steps to set it all up:

1. Create a new Data Extension with same field set.
2. In Automation Studio create new SQL Query Activity.
3. Write the query and select the newly created Data Extension as the target.
4. Check syntax / Save.
5. Test it. If all works, then schedule the Automation to run by some period of time, like once in an hour or day.